# Get Device Type/ Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After looking on SO in to how to detect users device here: [iOS - How to get device make and model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make)

I  made a quick test app to display an alert depending on device.  I get no alert from this code.  What am I missing/doing wrong here?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <sys/utsname.h>

 NSString* machineName()
{
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);

return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}



@interface ViewController ()


@end




- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {

if ([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]){


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Checking device iphone5" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];




    } else  if ([machineName() isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]){



    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Checking device iphone4" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];

     }


  }
```

Comment: can you log machineName() and see what is the result?

Comment: Did you try to single-step in the debugger to solve the problem?

Comment: You might also want to check to see if the string contains the first part of the string because a new phone will have a different model number.

Comment: @ elio.d logged machine getting 2013-02-05 21:26:05.040 hgfdsa[13188:c07] x86_64

Comment: Martin R will have to research that as never heard of it and get back to you. @Scott, roger that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `machine` field of `struct utsname` is the machine hardware platform and that is `"x86_64"` if the program is running in the iOS Simulator.

Only on a real device you will get strings like `"iPhone5,1"`.

Comment: Of Course! Thank you, getting the right output string now, just no alert fired on device

Comment: @JSA986: What string do you get now?

Comment: My apologies, I set it to iphone5.2 and all good thanks on my device for the final piece of the puzzle!