# is iPhone 5 always Returns False

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iphone-5, ios-universal-app

I am using the following code (in **AppDelegate**) to detect if the device is iPhone 5

`bool isiPhone5 = CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136));`

it returns false always. this is not the first time I used that code. eventhe NSLog for that returns {320, 480}

`NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size));`

**NOTE:** The app was for iPad only and then I made it universal. so I will have 2 storyBoards that is why I need the detection code.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you try this on the real device ?

Comment: `([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)`

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama NO, but that code worked before on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out.

**Solution**

Because the App was for iPad only the **Default-568h@2x.png** doesn't exist in the project. so after adding it all work properly.

**Note** and I dont need the above code because after making the app universal in the xcode project setting there is a part for **iPhone/iPod Deployment info** configurations (icons,mainStoryBorad,default screens ....) where I can setup the iPhone5 storybord after adding it to the project.

Answer (score 1):

This should work mate,

```
 bool isiPhone5 = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568);
```

and make sure you use 4-inch simulator

[image]

Comment: yes I did that and i am sure. i have developed 15 iPhone 5 apps but this is the first time it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To identify iphone 5 try this

```
  if( [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568){

    //iphone 5 
 }
  else
 {
    // less than iphone 5 
 }
```

Comment: its working for me friend now got solution @Bobj-C

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code. You can try this:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Then you can do:

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wrote this in my AppDelegate and it worked for me.

Comment: @Nammet yes I know, also my question's code worked for me in other projects but I don't why specially in this project it doen't work

Comment: Just to recheck, have you added all required frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define IS_iPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

if(IS_iPHONE_5)
{
    //Do something
}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See Below One

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
if( [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568){

  //iPhone5 Device
}
else
{
    // Normal iPhone device
}

}
```

EDIT: [see same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

-(NSString *)getModel {
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *model = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:model encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
free(model);
return deviceModel;
}
```

this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make) should help