# How can I check if device is 4 or 4s?

Tags: iphone, ios, device

How can I check if device is 4 or 4s?

Is there a way for me to do this?  I want to check because I am using a `UINavigationBar` blur, and it for my situation it doesn't look good without the blur, so I will change it if it is an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 6):

Ypu can do it like this:

```
 #import <sys/utsname.h>

    NSString*
    machineName()
    {
        struct utsname systemInfo;
        uname(&systemInfo);

        return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
```

The result should be like this:

```
//Simultor
@"i386"      on 32-bit Simulator
@"x86_64"    on 64-bit Simulator

//iPhone
@"iPhone1,1" on iPhone
@"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G
@"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS
@"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4 (GSM)
@"iPhone3,3" on iPhone 4 (CDMA/Verizon/Sprint)
@"iPhone4,1" on iPhone 4S
@"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5 (model A1428, AT&T/Canada)
@"iPhone5,2" on iPhone 5 (model A1429, everything else)
@"iPhone5,3" on iPhone 5c (model A1456, A1532 | GSM)
@"iPhone5,4" on iPhone 5c (model A1507, A1516, A1526 (China), A1529 | Global)
@"iPhone6,1" on iPhone 5s (model A1433, A1533 | GSM)
@"iPhone6,2" on iPhone 5s (model A1457, A1518, A1528 (China), A1530 | Global)
@"iPhone7,1" on iPhone 6 Plus
@"iPhone7,2" on iPhone 6
@"iPhone8,1" on iPhone 6S
@"iPhone8,2" on iPhone 6S Plus
@"iPhone8,4" on iPhone SE
@"iPhone9,1" on iPhone 7 (CDMA)
@"iPhone9,3" on iPhone 7 (GSM)
@"iPhone9,2" on iPhone 7 Plus (CDMA)
@"iPhone9,4" on iPhone 7 Plus (GSM)

//iPad 1
@"iPad1,1" on iPad - Wifi (model A1219)
@"iPad1,1" on iPad - Wifi + Cellular (model A1337)

//iPad 2
@"iPad2,1" - Wifi (model A1395)
@"iPad2,2" - GSM (model A1396)
@"iPad2,3" - 3G (model A1397)
@"iPad2,4" - Wifi (model A1395)

// iPad Mini
@"iPad2,5" - Wifi (model A1432)
@"iPad2,6" - Wifi + Cellular (model  A1454)
@"iPad2,7" - Wifi + Cellular (model  A1455)

//iPad 3
@"iPad3,1" - Wifi (model A1416)
@"iPad3,2" - Wifi + Cellular (model  A1403)
@"iPad3,3" - Wifi + Cellular (model  A1430)

//iPad 4
@"iPad3,4" - Wifi (model A1458)
@"iPad3,5" - Wifi + Cellular (model  A1459)
@"iPad3,6" - Wifi + Cellular (model  A1460)

//iPad AIR
@"iPad4,1" - Wifi (model A1474)
@"iPad4,2" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1475)
@"iPad4,3" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1476)

// iPad Mini 2
@"iPad4,4" - Wifi (model A1489)
@"iPad4,5" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1490)
@"iPad4,6" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1491)

// iPad Mini 3
@"iPad4,7" - Wifi (model A1599)
@"iPad4,8" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1600)
@"iPad4,9" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1601)

// iPad Mini 4
@"iPad5,1" - Wifi (model A1538)
@"iPad5,2" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1550)

//iPad AIR 2
@"iPad5,3" - Wifi (model A1566)
@"iPad5,4" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1567)

// iPad PRO 12.9"
@"iPad6,3" - Wifi (model A1673)
@"iPad6,4" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1674)
@"iPad6,4" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1675)

//iPad PRO 9.7"
@"iPad6,7" - Wifi (model A1584)
@"iPad6,8" - Wifi + Cellular (model A1652)

//iPod Touch
@"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch
@"iPod2,1"   on iPod Touch Second Generation
@"iPod3,1"   on iPod Touch Third Generation
@"iPod4,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
@"iPod7,1"   on iPod Touch 6th Generation
```

Comment: Or you can just add a comment to link to the actual answer .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197770/1407017

Comment: Using literals looks a lot cleaner! like so... return @(systemInfo.machine);