# Detecting IPhone, IPad, IPod

Tags: java, ios, iphone, jsp, user-agent

Hy! A similar questions have been asked on this platform (stackoverflow) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make), etc. But I need to get the mobile details upon when an Iphone,Ipad or an Ipod user will visit my site I will get his details using Javascript, or Java/Jsp/Servlets. The details I need are as follows:

```
Model Name        // IPhone 3g, Iphone 4s, IPhone 5s, Iphone 5c, IPad 1 , etc
OS Type           //IOS
OS Version        //6.1.1 or 6.1.2 etc
```

According to my research many users have done through javascript but they only just detect Model not complete with 4s etc. Also I came across [this](http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings) which give specific code against UserAgent of different Iphone/Ipad/Ipod but when I tested through online simulators there were 50% chances of there correction. Kindly guide.

### Edit:

There is a correction! I came to know that in user-agent there is a build version (Build Version of an OS) included through which we can check that that a specific OS say 6 was released for multiple devices say Iphone 3gs, 4s , Ipad and so on. But is there a build for hardware specific firmware which uniquely identifies the device?

Comment: Only model should matter to you not OS version, since all you really need to know is the screen size, and whether its Iphone or Anroid I guess.

Comment: Do you want these all details using  native objective-c code or using java script???

Comment: @NiravPatel I need to know these details using Java or Jsp/Servlets or through Javascript.