# Extract & Display information of IOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to create an app to extract and display information of IOS devices. Device information includes:

- Make
- Model
- Serial Number
- IMEI

Please help, how to extract those data with objective-c ?

Comment: Access to identifiers that uniquely identify a device is not permitted.  But for make and model, you can use `uname` from `sys/utsname`.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make)

Answer (score 1):

[The `UIDevice` developer reference is a great source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/name). The article is very straightforward, but here is the jist of it.

```
UIDevice *device  = [UIDevice sharedDevice];
NSString *name    = [device name];
NSString *sysname = [device systemName]; 
NSString *model   = [device model];
float     battery = [device batteryLevel];
```

`UIDevice` class offers many ways to gain information on the current state of the users device and information about the specific device.

Answer (score 0):

IMEI and serial number cannot be accessed by apps unless they use private APIs. Apple will reject your app if it uses any private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Make and model are available through the `UIDevice` class.  As noted, IMEI and Serial Number are not available through public API's.

Comment: how to get imei and serial number with private api ?