# iOS 8.x alternative to detect iPhone 5s, using [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0

Tags: objective-c, ios8, iphone-5, bounds, mainscreen

In iOS versions prior to iOS 8, to check whether the device is iPhone 5/iPhone 5s, checking [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0 was enough. But in iOS 8.x onwards, this check may fail as the bounds are now orientation dependant. I need a solution to identify the iPhone 5s, 6 and 6+ devices without checking the iOS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to detect the devices using the following macros. This will be useful if you want identify the device, to perform some update on views(like updating frames on orientation changes). If you exactly want the device model/make, use this link ([ios iphone get device model and make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make)) instead.

```
#define IS_IPHONE       ((int)(MAX([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)) == 480)
#define IS_IPHONE5      ((int)(MAX([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)) == 568)
#define IS_IPHONE6      ((int)(MAX([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)) == 667)
#define IS_IPHONE6PLUS  ((int)(MAX([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)) == 736)
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if app is in "zoom" mode (splash screen missing for 6 or 6+)

Comment: @l0gg3r:You are right, in zoomed mode this will fail. In zoomed mode The iPhone5 check will be true for iPhone6 and iPhone6+ also. So I will update the answer to cover that also.

Comment: @l0gg3r:I said it was working for me is because, my requirement is to identify the device, to update the view's frames on orientation update. My app support both new resolutions, so no worries about zoomed mode. Also if the app is running in zoomed mode, we don't need to worry about that; the system will handle that case. Set the view's frames for iPhone 5 resolution and the system will zoom/scale it for the new resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0
```

and `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` to identify iPhone 6 and 6+

Note that this will not work if application is working on "zoomed" mode.
In this case iPhone 6 and 6+ will give scale 2.0

Comment: Could you please explain what's zoomed mode for iPhone 6 & 6+? Please give a basic idea. I am new to this.

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick if you don't specify Splash images for iPhone 6 / 6+ (in ImageAssets for example) application will start working in zoomed mode, and the screen bounds will be 320 x 568 on both iPhone 6, 6+

Comment: Thanks a lot friend !!! I really don't what size of splash screens I should be adding to support iPhone 6 & 6+. Any help on this?

Comment: iPhone 6 - 750 x 1334 pixels, iPhone 6+ 1242 x 2208 pixels

Comment: Thanks again. So, only adding the above two splash screens will do the work for me. Am I correct? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, your application will start supporting iPhone 6 and 6+ (so you need to start supporting another screen size), I've added a small guide that can be helpful http://i.imgur.com/iONhe52.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64691/discussion-between-rashmi-ranjan-mallick-and-l0gg3r).