# How to get Device name when change device type in simulator programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, device-name

I'm using the below method:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h> // import it in your header or implementation file.

NSString* deviceName()
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

The result is:

```
@"i386"      on 32-bit Simulator
@"x86_64"    on 64-bit Simulator
@"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch
@"iPod2,1"   on iPod Touch Second Generation
@"iPod3,1"   on iPod Touch Third Generation
@"iPod4,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
@"iPhone1,1" on iPhone
@"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G
@"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS
@"iPad1,1"   on iPad
@"iPad2,1"   on iPad 2
@"iPad3,1"   on 3rd Generation iPad
@"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4
@"iPhone4,1" on iPhone 4S
@"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5 (model A1428, AT&T/Canada)
@"iPhone5,2" on iPhone 5 (model A1429, everything else)
@"iPad3,4" on 4th Generation iPad
@"iPad2,5" on iPad Mini
@"iPhone5,3" on iPhone 5c (model A1456, A1532 | GSM)
@"iPhone5,4" on iPhone 5c (model A1507, A1516, A1526 (China), A1529 | Global)
@"iPhone6,1" on iPhone 5s (model A1433, A1533 | GSM)
@"iPhone6,2" on iPhone 5s (model A1457, A1518, A1528 (China), A1530 | Global)
@"iPad4,1" on 5th Generation iPad (iPad Air) - Wifi
@"iPad4,2" on 5th Generation iPad (iPad Air) - Cellular
@"iPad4,4" on 2nd Generation iPad Mini - Wifi
@"iPad4,5" on 2nd Generation iPad Mini - Cellular
@"iPhone7,1" on iPhone 6 Plus
@"iPhone7,2" on iPhone 6
```

I got `x86_64` always. But I wish to get iphone4 when I select the 4s simulator iPhone6 when I select the iPhone 6 simulator.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-iphone-get-device-model-and-make check this lots of answer availbale here

Comment: But all of them gives only common result as "simulator". My requirement is to get the model selected (like simulator iPhone4, simulator  iPhone6 etc). Hope you got me

Comment: it works in device fine. but not getting the name in simulator.