# How to get the different models of the iPhone 5s?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, theos, tweak

I need to get info about device model, in particular for the iPhone 5s.

These are the different models:
- A1433
- A1533 | GSM
- A1457
- A1518
- A1528 (China)
- A1530 | Global

But I can divide them just into 2 categories:
1) model A1433, A1533 | GSM
2) model A1457, A1518, A1528 (China), A1530 | Global

So, is there a way to get the single device mode and not the whole category?

Comment: Where is your code? And why do you need that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-how-to-get-device-make-and-model You need `uname` for your case. For iPhone 5s you will either get `iPhone6,1` or `iPhone6,2`

Comment: I know I can use this, but in this way I will het iPhone 6,1 or iPhone 6,2. I need the exact model, for example A1433- Thanks

Comment: You can't determine A1433 from A1533, Apple has no public API for that (you can only know private iPhone model 6,1; 6,2 etc.). I don't get why would you need that anyway.

Comment: Because I'm developing a JB tweak that will interact with internet connection. Some little things change depending on the exact iPhone model