# Set different font size for iPhone 5 and 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, resize, font-size

I have searched for but not found an answer to this yet.

I would like to set different font sizes of labels for iPhone 5 and 6. I know that I can set specific layout for Compact Width, but both 5 and 6 belong to that group. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Then you can do this task very easily. you will get + option before font option in attribute inspector. Where you can set multiplier value

Comment: @amelie... see the answer below posted. i find one answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 480 {
// iPhone 4
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)     

} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568 {
// IPhone 5
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)

} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375 {
// iPhone 6
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)

} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414 {
// iPhone 6+
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)

} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 768 {
// iPad
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20)

}
```

Or you can get the device using the Apple's API and perform the rest of the logic to set the font size. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk/3950748#3950748)

Comment: your answer is correct. and yesterday i uprooted for same. Welcome.

Comment: You should not use hard-coded size to get device model

Answer (score 1):

You can get the model of the iPhone and compare it to iPhone5, 5s, 5c, 6, and set the font accordingly. You should not use hard-coded sizes to get the device model, but you can get it with Apple's API. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3950748/1282896) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655825/1282896).

Answer (score 1):

My helper extension:

```
extension UIFont {
    static var sizeMultiplier: CGFloat {
        return UIDevice.current.isPhone5 ? 0.85 : 1
    }

    static func regular(_ size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Regular", size: size * sizeMultiplier)!
    }

    static func bold(_ size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Bold", size: size * sizeMultiplier)!
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
titleLabel.font = .bold(16)
```

I'm also looking for a solution to attach the iPhone5-specific size in the runtime attributes.