# swift check if device is iphone 5 or 6 or ipad

Tags: iphone, swift, user-interface

Is there a function to check what device the user is using?

In one of my View Controllers I have a view inside a scrollview. In that view I have some text inputs. Then I change the height position on that view in order to prevent the keyboard from being on top of the view/inputs.

I don't need to move the view as much on an iPhone 6 compared to an iPhone 5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - How to get device make and model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-how-to-get-device-make-and-model)

Comment: This is a common question. Check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift

Comment: why not use auto layout or get window height to work it out?

Comment: @NSDeveloper I have some other stuff that I am going to run depending on what device it is :)

Answer (score -1):

```
print(UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
```

Will get you want you want.

Comment: That will print eg "Stevens Iphone"