# How to get iOS device model number (eg. A1530)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm wondering is that possible to get the iOS device model number programmatically. I mean the device model on the back of iPhone. It's always in this format "AXXXX".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-how-to-get-device-make-and-model

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift

Comment: did you got what you were looking for? I need the same model number

Answer (score 2):

With a little use of private API it is possible

```
let device = UIDevice.current
var selector = NSSelectorFromString("deviceInfoForKey:")
if !device.responds(to: selector) {
    selector = NSSelectorFromString("_deviceInfoForKey:")
}
if device.responds(to: selector) {
    if let unmanagedModel = device.perform(selector, with:"ModelNumber") {
        let model = unmanagedModel.takeRetainedValue() as! String
        print("Device hardware model: \(model)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
let myDevice = UIDevice.currentDevice()
let deviceModel = myDevice.model
```

Comment: This is not what I expect. It only can return iPhone or iPad.