# How to identify that an iOS device doesn't have 3.5 mm jack

Tags: ios, iphone

With iPhone 7 and 7 plus in market, we are aware that the 3.5 mm jack no more exists. Moving forward any new device will not have this jack.
So, now do we have any API that tells us that the device doesn't have this jack anymore rather than comparing with the device name provided in this below link.
[iOS - How to get device make and model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-how-to-get-device-make-and-model/11197770#11197770)
How do we know that the specific device doesn't have a 3.5 mm jack?