# Identify hardware type in a web app

Tags: web-applications, device

One of my clients sells accessories for tablet cases. I would like to develop a web app that identifies the type of device of the user and redirects them to a webpage depending on the type of device. It doesn't need to be their unique device just the model number.

It seems to be possible on a local app, but is it possible on a web app?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but You don't have specialized questions, what language are you using?, you want get this information on frontend or backend?

In PHP you can get this information by library:

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

In JavaScript you can use:

https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/

or look

[Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

maybe another language?

Comment: Sorry, basically is this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-how-to-get-device-make-and-model possible in a web app? Thank you for your response and please excuse my ignorance. I'm really just trying to work out if it's possible or not before looking into it any further.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you must analyze user agent variable for this. The librarys that I sent you are doing it for you (If we talk about PHP or JS - because I still do not know which language you want to use?)