# iPhone X vs others status bar hidden

Tags: ios11, uistatusbar, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

Apple advices us to avoid hiding status bar on **iPhone X**. My app hides status bar for all devices. But does it give a clean way to hide status bar on all devices where the bar doesn't interferes with UI as in **iPhone X**? Also I see status bar gets invisible in `landscape mode` in `simulator`. Not sure if it is a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 1):

*Q: Status bar in iPhone-x*

**The status bar displays information people find useful.**

Based on your UI & requirement you should design

Acoording to [Apple Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/)-

> If your app currently hides the status bar, reconsider that decision
>   on iPhone X. The display height on iPhone provides more vertical space
>   for content than the displays of 4.7" iPhones, and the status bar
>   occupies an area of the screen your app probably won't fully utilize.
>   The status bar also displays information people find useful. It should
>   only be hidden in exchange for added value

*Q: Also I see status bar gets invisible in landscape mode in simulator*

Yes, in landscape iPhone-x hides status bar

[See video of iPhone-X hands on experience at 0:29](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZTGeQ5msaU&feature=youtu.be&t=29)
I just checked in **iOS11** with iPhone SE & iPhone-6s which hides status bar automatically in landscape mode.
Also when you are in landscape mode there is no in-call-status bar in **iOS11**

Comment: Ok got it. What is the way to hide status bar on devices like iPhone X where it does not interfere with UI?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679853/7576100)