# In the Xcode iOS simulator, how can I tell what device it is simulating?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

You can get the model identifier of an iOS device using the `uname` system call, as described in several answers here on Stack Overflow (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/how-to-get-device-make-and-model-on-ios/11197770#11197770)).

If you're running in the simulator, this will tell you the architecture of your computer.  Is there any way of finding out the model it is simulating?

Comment: I realize you mean programmatically, but I was tempted to say "look at the title bar." :-p

Comment: Haha! Yes, programmatically. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the environment variable `SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER`. This returns the same value you would see on the equivalent physical device. For example on the iPhone 6 Plus simulator it will be "iPhone7,1".