# How to get app information like app version, device os version in ios using Appium?

Tags: ios, appium, instruments, xcuitest

I am testing the app using appium and integrating the test output in testrail. I need to add the device and app information in the testrail. In android i am able to get app and device information like device model, device version and app version using adb command like following:

```
adb -s 012313gasda shell getprop ro.product.model
adb -s 012313gasda shell getprop ro.build.version.release
adb -s 012313gasda shell dumpsys package com.test.app |grep versionName
```

How can i achieve the same information for ios? using following command will return you the device name and OS version as set in desired capabilities

```
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("deviceName").toString();
driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("CapabilityType.VERSION").toString();
```

Is there anyway to get device and app information for ios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar to adb using ideviceinfo such as in this SO post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55028994/8016330

```
PRODUCT_NAME=$(ideviceinfo --udid $DEVICE_UDID --key ProductName)
PRODUCT_TYPE=$(ideviceinfo --udid $DEVICE_UDID --key ProductType)
PRODUCT_VERSION=$(ideviceinfo --udid $DEVICE_UDID --key ProductVersion)
```

HTH

James

Comment: Thanks to you, I am able to get ProductName, ProductType, ProductVersion. Is there any similar way to get app version using bundle id or ipa file?

Comment: I am able to get app version using `ideviceinstaller -l | grep appBundleId`.