# How to find installed app version through automated script?

Tags: selenium, appium

I have a requirement to find the version of an app installed in mobile device and if the version is not latest then install latest version.
Here how do i automate to find installed app version? I am using appium & selenium to automate my scripts.

Comment: how would you have done it manually? start with the steps and just automate it!

Comment: That we can do but is there a way to find version of installed app directly without navigating to app?

Comment: Is the version stored in a plist or manifest doc that can be extracted programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find android  app version you can do it using shell command

```
String cmd = "adb shell dumpsys package your.app.package.name.here |grep versionName";
Process process = null;
try {
     process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
     String appVersion = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())).readLine();
        System.out.println("appVersion = "+appVersion);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For more info check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372031/how-to-get-app-information-like-app-version-device-os-version-in-ios-using-appi)