# how to get phone's model name in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-privateapi

I've been searching a while about this and I've found out that this can't be get from `UIDevice.current.model`, because it returns just `iPhone`. there were several answers pointing to this code:

```swift
if let simulatorModelIdentifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] { 
    return simulatorModelIdentifier 
}

var sysinfo = utsname()
uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value
let deviceModel = String(bytes: Data(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, count: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN)), encoding: .ascii)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)

return deviceModel ?? ""
```

by the way I'm not sure that this uses public or private api and it seems like private api for me.

**Question**
is this code using any private api?

Comment: Have you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197770/6678991

Comment: Did you check all the answers in the attached question by @Mahdi-Malv? There are correct solution to get the right code and mapping from code to model name.

Comment: yea, I've already upvoted @Mahdi-Malv 's comment. by the way Gael 's answer is all I wanted to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not use any private API.

`uname` function returns a POSIX structure containing name and information about current kernel. The `machine` variable contains an hardware identifier. You'll need to convert this identifier to a more friendly name, but that's all.

You can use `man uname` in your terminal for more information about the function.