# How to detect model of iOS in titanium framework

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-sdk

Example :
iPad pro 3rd generation onward due to introduce bottom black bar notch.
Not exist in iPad pro 1st and 2nd generation. All four generation has same resolution. 1024 X 1366
if i fixed for this resolution it will impact 1st and 2nd generation.

```
if(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight === 1366){
}
```

This code cause issue to other iPad pro generation.

Answer (score 3):

Titanium provides platform-identification properties in the Ti.Platform namespace that you can use for conditional branching within your code.

if used `Ti.Platform.model` its return model values, but it has some mapping to understand which model exactly.
https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Platform-property-model

Following are mapping list :

```
["iPod5,1": "iPod Touch 5",
"iPod7,1": "iPod Touch 6",
"iPhone3,1": "iPhone 4",
"iPhone3,2": "iPhone 4",
"iPhone3,3": "iPhone 4",
"iPhone4,1": "iPhone 4s",
"iPhone5,1": "iPhone 5",
"iPhone5,2": "iPhone 5",
"iPhone5,3": "iPhone 5c",
"iPhone5,4": "iPhone 5c",
"iPhone6,1": "iPhone 5s",
"iPhone6,2": "iPhone 5s",
"iPhone7,2": "iPhone 6",
"iPhone7,1": "iPhone 6 Plus",
"iPhone8,1": "iPhone 6s",
"iPhone8,2": "iPhone 6s Plus",
"iPhone9,1": "iPhone 7",
"iPhone9,3": "iPhone 7",
"iPhone9,2": "iPhone 7 Plus",
"iPhone9,4": "iPhone 7 Plus",
"iPhone8,4": "iPhone SE",
"iPhone10,1": "iPhone 8",
"iPhone10,4": "iPhone 8",
"iPhone10,2": "iPhone 8 Plus",
"iPhone10,5": "iPhone 8 Plus",
"iPhone10,3": "iPhone X",
"iPhone10,6": "iPhone X",
"iPhone11,2": "iPhone XS",
"iPhone11,4": "iPhone XS Max",
"iPhone11,6": "iPhone XS Max",
"iPhone11,8": "iPhone XR",
"iPhone12,1": "iPhone 11",
"iPhone12,3": "iPhone 11 Pro",
"iPhone12,5": "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
"iPad2,1": "iPad 2",
"iPad2,2": "iPad 2",
"iPad2,3": "iPad 2",
"iPad2,4": "iPad 2",
"iPad3,1": "iPad 3",
"iPad3,2": "iPad 3",
"iPad3,3": "iPad 3",
"iPad3,4": "iPad 4",
"iPad3,5": "iPad 4",
"iPad3,6": "iPad 4",
"iPad4,1": "iPad Air",
"iPad4,2": "iPad Air",
"iPad4,3": "iPad Air",
"iPad5,3": "iPad Air 2",
"iPad5,4": "iPad Air 2",
"iPad6,11": "iPad 5",
"iPad6,12": "iPad 5",
"iPad7,5": "iPad 6",
"iPad7,6": "iPad 6",
"iPad2,5": "iPad Mini",
"iPad2,6": "iPad Mini",
"iPad2,7": "iPad Mini",
"iPad4,4": "iPad Mini 2",
"iPad4,5": "iPad Mini 2",
"iPad4,6": "iPad Mini 2",
"iPad4,7": "iPad Mini 3",
"iPad4,8": "iPad Mini 3",
"iPad4,9": "iPad Mini 3",
"iPad5,1": "iPad Mini 4",
"iPad5,2": "iPad Mini 4",
"iPad6,3": "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
"iPad6,4": "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
"iPad6,7": "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
"iPad6,8": "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
"iPad7,1": "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
"iPad7,2": "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
"iPad7,3": "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
"iPad7,4": "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
"iPad8,1": "iPad Pro (11-inch)",
"iPad8,2": "iPad Pro (11-inch)",
"iPad8,3": "iPad Pro (11-inch)",
"iPad8,4": "iPad Pro (11-inch)",
"iPad8,5": "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
"iPad8,6": "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
"iPad8,7": "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
"iPad8,8": "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
"AppleTV5,3": "Apple TV",
"AppleTV6,2": "Apple TV 4K",
"AudioAccessory1,1": "HomePod",
"i386": "32 bit Simulator",
"x86_64": "64 bit Simulator"
]
```

Reference for this : [How to get device make and model on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/how-to-get-device-make-and-model-on-ios/11197770#11197770)

We can write code to detect model like :

when running on virtual device or simulator in xcode its return like "iPad8,5 (Simulator)" and when actual device it returned "iPad8,5"

```
if (Ti.Platform.model === "iPad8,5 (Simulator)" ||
Ti.Platform.model === "iPad8,5"){
return true;
}
else {
return false;
}
```

This property not only related to iOS, its for all type of devices. I have mentioned only iOS specific.

Help done by [@miga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193915/miga)

Updated list can be found here : https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Main_Page
https://gist.github.com/adamawolf/3048717

Step to get device Id :

Click on device -> go to respective page
[image]