# Determine if Device is running at 120hz instead of 60hz in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

What is the best way to check whether or not an iPhone (and possibly future iPads) are running 120hz rather than the traditional 60hz?

I understand there are ways to [check devices and iOS versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/how-to-get-device-make-and-model-on-ios), but is there a way to determine if a device is 120hz?

To provide some context I use a GameDev platform that has always supported 60hz, and it seems the games run at 2x speed on iPhone 13 Pros running 120hz.

I was hoping there would be a simple test which I could use to set the frame rate accordingly.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as 60 Hz **or** 120 Hz.

To quote [Apple's press release](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2017/06/ipad-pro-10-5-and-12-9-inch-models-introduces-worlds-most-advanced-display-breakthrough-performance/) (emphasis mine):

> The stunning, redesigned Retina display in iPad Pro features ProMotion, a new technology that delivers refresh rates of **up to** 120Hz for fluid scrolling, greater responsiveness and smoother motion content.
> ...
> ProMotion also improves display quality and reduces power consumption by by **automatically adjusting the display refresh rate to match the movement of the content**.

It can be 60 Hz, 120 Hz, or anywhere in between (and in the future, the max will undoubtedly go above 120 Hz, too).

I don't even think there's a minimum frame rate (I can't test that though). Conceivably you might even have a 0 Hz framerate if the screen content hasn't changed at all.

I think you should probably use [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) to time your frames, at whatever rate the system has chosen.

Comment: Oh I See. That makes sense. Thank you for the insight. I will look into `CADisplayLink`.