# How do I get device platform type in Swift?

Tags: swift2, platform, uidevice

I want to have a section in my app that shows the device type so I can make it noticeable to show that the device is supported. How do I get this? I tried

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().
```

and there was no platform type.

Answer (score 2):

Why cant you use:

```
UIDevice.current.systemName
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this [Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620229/how-can-i-get-iphone-device-type).

I didn't get why you want to show the user if the device is supported.
The user shoudn't be able to download your app if the device is not compatible, and you can limit what device can download your app [by doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191657/restrict-to-certain-ios-target-devices-for-app-store-submission).

[This link](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/05/02/how-to-indicate-what-devices-are-supported-by-your-ios-app) can also help you decide what UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key you should use

Comment: Yeah, that's the property I was using but it doesn't seem to work in Swift (first link).